# Reducing storage space as much as possible in spark when dealing with columns with many repetitive values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame of poi data with their corresponding city/states. I am looking for a way to minimize the data storage space for this data as much as possible in pyspark. One feature I thought might be useful to consider, is that the city and state columns, contain lots of duplicate data.

```
+------+---------+---------+
|  poi | city    |state    |
+------+---------+---------+
| abcd | New York| New York|
| cdef | New York| New York|
| xcvd | Chicago | Illinois|
| hjkq | New York| New York|
| acdr | Austin  | Texas   |
+------+---------+---------+
```

I thought if I read the data, partition it by city and state, and then save it to the disk, it might save more space.

```
df = sqlContext.read.csv(inFile,sep="\t", quote=None, header=False)
df.repartition("city",'state').write.option("header", "true").partitionBy(["city",'state']).csv(outFile,compression="gzip")
```

That did not save any space compare to the original gz file. I won't be querying this table a lot so the main objective is just to save disk space. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: try to save using orc or paraquet formats and using snappy encoding

Comment: I did in parquet. still didnt make a difference size wize

Comment: I mean, compare to gz , it does not save space

Comment: What if you create two more tables/datasets? namely `city` and `state`, in which you will save the pair {name, id} i.e: {florida, 4}, {chicago, 6}. Then you go to your original table and replace name -> id on the state and city columns respectively. For the id column pick up `ShortType` (only 2 bytes),which is sufficient to store all the available states and cities. Now you should have all names replaced by the id. You just need to join them in order to get the desired dataset. Of course you need to spent some extra CPU for the join,at the same time this should save you some considerable space